# jQuery Check if Last Child Correct Syntax

Tags: jquery

I wrote some jQuery that uses two if statements that check if the current element is the last child or first child before attempting to execute some more code. The current syntax I have used is:

```
<script>
    $('#right').on('mousewheel', function(e) {

        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {

            if (current.is(':first-child') == false) {
                $('.scroll-item.active').removeClass('active').prev('.scroll-item').addClass('active');
            }

        } else {

            if (current.is(':last-child') == false) {
                $('.scroll-item.active').removeClass('active').next('.scroll-item').addClass('active');
            }

        }

        current = $('.scroll-item.active');
        next = current.next('.scroll-item');

    });
</script>
```

I am curious if there is a way to use `.not()` instead of `is.()` to check if the element is not the `:last-child` or the `:first-child`? The way I currently have it seems like overkill.

Comment: even better `:not()` selector i.e. `current.is(':not(:last-child)')`

Comment: The `.not()` function is not for testing things, it's used for filtering a selection using another selector.

Comment: Thanks guys! @Satpal's suggestion is pretty well the syntax I was hoping to achieve, and it seems like it's the best available.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
if (!current.is(':first-child')) { ... }
```

&

```
if (!current.is(':last-child')) { ... }
```